# Pass a variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I'm trying to pass a variable from one function to another. I thought this would work but I get undefined.

```
function launch(){
    amount();
    finalize(theAmount);
}

function amount(){
    var theAmount = prompt('How much?');
    return theAmount;
}

function finalize(theAmount){
     alert(theAmount);   
}

launch();
```

Comment: "theAmount" is lost on the stack bro. You could just declare it outside the functions (not best practice but works though).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access the variable which is defined in some other function. Thats NOT possible because of [`Javascript's scope restrictions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope). You have to pass the return value as it is or you have to assign it to a variable and then pass it to the function.

Either this

```
function launch(){
    finalize(amount());
}
```

Or

```
function launch(){
    var theAmount = amount();
    finalize(theAmount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are calling amount function in lunch function which is returns a value but you haven't receive it.

try this to modify lunch function as

```
function launch(){
    var theAmount = amount();
    finalize(theAmount);
}

function amount(){
    var theAmount = prompt('How much?');
    return theAmount;
}

function finalize(theAmount){
     alert(theAmount);   
}

launch();
```